# Is the Godeaux surface irrational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Studying examples of surfaces of general type, I've found the Godeaux surface. Here is a link for the [definition of Godeaux's surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godeaux_surface)

How can I see directly that this surface is not ruled?

Comment: A surface of general type cannot be ruled. Do you know why the Godeaux surface is of general type? (By the way, the questions in the title and in the body do not match.)

Comment: i know that a minimal surface is of general type if and only if $K^2_S>0$ and $S$ is irrational.  I've proved that the self intersection of $K_S$ is positive and i need to prove that the surface is not irrational.

Comment: Do you define the Godeaux surface as a quotient of a degree-5 Fermat hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$? Then its canonical bundle should be ample, because you can average a positive metric on the canonical bundle of the Fermat hypersurface and get a positive metric on the quotient, thus the surface is of general type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the criterion you mention in the comments, if you want to know that the Godeaux surface $S$ is of general type, it's enough to know it's irrational. But that is true for a very easy topological reason. Every smooth rational projective variety is simply connected, but $S$ is covered by the Fermat quintic $F$ with deck group $G=\mathbf Z/5 \mathbf Z$, so $\pi_1(S) \cong G$ is nontrivial.

On the other hand, general type means that $K_S$ is positive, in some sense, and it's useful to be able to see the "positivity" of $K_S$ more directly. In that vein, let me give a more elementary (and more algebraic) variant of Gunnar's nice comment. I will prove that the some multiple of the canonical bundle of the Godeaux surface has at least one global section, and this is enough to conclude that it isn't ruled (and hence certainly isn't rational). Souping up my argument one could show directly that the canonical bundle is big, and even ample; this would give general type while avoiding the criterion the OP mentions in comments. I leave this stronger result as an exercise.

Call the Godeaux surface $S$. Then, as mentioned above, $S$ can be defined as the quotient of the Fermat quintic $F \subset \mathbf P^3$ by the (free) action of the cyclic group $G$ of order 5.

Adjunction shows that $K_F$ is the restriction of $O_{\mathbf P^3}(1)$. In particular, $K_F$ has nonvanishing global sections. Choose one such section $\omega$.

Now let $$\Omega = \bigotimes_{g \in G} g^* \omega.$$

By construction, $\Omega$ is a nonvanishing $G$-invariant global section of $K_F^{\otimes 5}$. Therefore it descends via the quotient map $q:F \rightarrow S$ to a well-defined nonvanishing global section $\Omega_S$ of $K_S^{\otimes 5}$.

**Remark:** The construction above seems a bit over-the-top: why not just use $\sum_g g^* \omega$ instead to produce a $G$-invariant section of the canonical bundle $K_F$ instead? Well, I can't stop you from doing that, but's a good exercise to think about why it doesn't prove what we want. If you need a hint, see the nice answer of Clay Cordova [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21205/nef-divisors-with-few-global-sections/21254#21254).

Answer (score 0):

The Godeaux surface is of general type, hence has kodaira dimension $2$. A Ruled surface has kodaira dimension $-\infty$. Sorry for linking Wikipedia - can also be found in Hartshorne. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_dimension#Dimension_2)